# ConcurrentHashMap changes visible to all the threads?

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety, volatile, concurrenthashmap

I have a CHM defined as below. I am calling `setDataProcess` method from a single background thread whenever there is any update. And I am calling `getDataMapping` from multiple reader threads always.

```
private static final ConcurrentHashMap<ProcessType, Mapping> mappingsHolder = new ConcurrentHashMap<ProcessType, Mapping>();
private static final CountDownLatch hasInitialized = new CountDownLatch(ProcessType.values().length);

public static void setDataProcess(ProcessType processType, Mapping newMapData) {
    mappingsHolder.put(processType, newMapData);
    hasInitialized.countDown();
}

public static Mapping getDataMapping(ProcessType processType) {
    try {
        hasInitialized.await();
        return mappingsHolder.get(processType);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        throw new IllegalStateException(e);
    }
}
```

Question is - Any change in `mappingsHolder` CHM will be visible to all the reader threads instantly or I need to use volatile for that?

Comment: How hard is it to try an see ?

Comment: @Alp: for visibility issues, try-and-see is nontrivial. esp since if it fails it may be on different hardware with looser rules than x86.

Comment: Did you use the CountDownLatch so the getDataMapping can be invoked only after the mappingsHolder is filled?

Comment: @adhg Yes you are right.

Comment: Cool. Looks like the volatile in this case is redundant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I can see, you're using a `CountDownLatch` in the read method to wait until the count reaches zero. The count is apparently the number of enum constants in `ProcessType`. If this `CountDownLatch` is properly implemented, there shouldn't be a problem since according to the [javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html), there should be a happens-before relationship:

> Memory consistency effects: Until the count reaches zero, actions in a thread prior to calling `countDown()` *happen-before* actions following a successful return from a corresponding `await()` in another thread.

Ignoring the `CountDownLatch` factor, the [`ConcurrentHashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html) does not synchronize on a retrieval of a key but retrieves the most recent value corresponding to a key.

> Retrieval operations (including `get`) generally do not block, so may overlap with update operations (including `put` and `remove`). **Retrievals reflect the results of the most recently *completed* update operations holding upon their onset.**

This means changes done by a thread are visible to a thread reading a key. But the two can interfere.

Comment: CDL is for one time synchronization during the startup but after that it has to be atomic update so CHM changes will be visible to all the threads?

Comment: Thanks for an edit so that means it will be an atomic update and any changes  to CHM will be visible to all the threads right?

Answer (score 2):

The CountdownLatch makes sure that actions prior to countDown happen-before another thread's return from await, as [Manouti said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31212268/217324).

As for the ConcurrentHashMap, [the api documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html) reads:

> an update operation for a given key bears a happens-before relation with any (non-null) retrieval for that key reporting the updated value.

which should handle visibility of changes to the map to the threads reading from it.

Answer (score 0):

Since the value of the variable *(i.e.* the location in memory of the map) will not change, then I doubt that `volatile` will make a difference here.  The map-object, once allocated, won't be moving around.

But there is, as always, a potential timing issue:  the threads could read a value before or after you have changed it.  Basically, a `concurrentHashMap` won't be *destroyed* by being used by more than one thread at a time.  As such, it's a necessary feature.  But, that alone doesn't really address any other synchronization or notification requirements that the threads may require in order to successfully work together.